# ffmpeg AVFrame get full decoded data to char*

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I get Frames in loop and decode it with ffmpeg getting AVFrame as e result of it.

So I must get neccessary pixel data of frame into char* and give as a callback function's parameter. So how I can generete such char* array? In internet I saw some examples such as:

```
for(y=0; y<height; y++)
{
 fwrite(pFrame->data[0]+y*pFrame->linesize[0], 1, width*3, pFile);
}
```

or something like this. Is it true? And which size would be my char* ? As I see we write width*3 *height bytes?

Comment: Depends on the format of your frame. What format is it in?

Answer (score 2):

```
for(y=0; y<height; y++) { 
    fwrite(pFrame->data[0]+y*pFrame->linesize[0], 1, width*3, pFile);
}
```

Yes that's correct.
This is writing a line of 3byte/pixel (presumably RGB) from the AVFrame->data pointer.

ps. The reason for doing it like this is that the start of each row of data begins on a new 4byte memory boundary - the computer is more efficent at accessing memory in multiples of 32bits (4bytes). 
So if your pixel size (3bytes) and width aren't a multiple of 4 then you need to do this rather than simply copy `width*height*3` bytes of data.

Comment: As I understood it is a PPM format of pixel-data. How can I save full pixel data in bmp for example... ?

Comment: @mmmaaak - PPM is the easiest format to write directly. BMP is essentially the same but with a more complex header, if you are on windows the lib already contains code to write bmps, just search msdn

Comment: Related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047200/extract-rgb-values-from-a-avframe-ffmpeg-in-c