# Using ffMPEG on Windows with only the DLL's?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, ffmpeg

What I actually want is to [store frames of a video into a char array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9912873/ffmpeg-avframe-get-full-decoded-data-to-char), using ffMPEG.
Constraint is to use only MSVC. Not allowed to use the [Windows building tweak](http://libav.org/platform.html#Windows) due to maintainability issues.

So considered using the [shared build](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) to accomplish the task. It consists of only DLL's. No `lib` files, so I tried loading one of the DLL's using `HINSTANCE hInstLibrary = LoadLibrary("avcodec-54.dll");` and it works. But I couldn't find the interfaces of this DLL published anywhere. Could anyone help with this? How do I know which functions of the DLL I can call and what parameters I can pass it so that I can get the video frames?

Comment: A related page for using the dev builds: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11701635/use-ffmpeg-in-visual-studio. Believe me, it's a lot easier to write a program with the answer in this link than in the answer below, because the answer below necessitates loading a DLL function and using it as functionname_proc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the public interface of ffmpeg from

```
ffmpegdir/include/libavcodec/
ffmpegdir/include/libavformat/
etc.
```

for example, to open a file for reading, use avformat_open_input from ffmpegdir/include/libavformat/avformat.h

```
AVFormatContext * ctx= NULL;
int err = avformat_open_input(&ctx, file_name, NULL, NULL);
```

You can get the latest builds of ffmpeg from http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/

Public header files can be found in dev builds (http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win32/dev/).

**UPD:**
Here is a working example (no additional static linking)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>

typedef int (__cdecl *__avformat_open_input)(AVFormatContext **, const char *, AVInputFormat *, AVDictionary **);
typedef void (__cdecl *__av_register_all)(void);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    const char * ffp = "f:\\Projects\\Temp\\testFFMPEG\\Debug\\avformat-54.dll";
    HINSTANCE hinstLib = LoadLibraryA(ffp);
    __avformat_open_input __avformat_open_input_proc  = (__avformat_open_input)GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "avformat_open_input");

    __av_register_all __av_register_all_proc = (__av_register_all)GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "av_register_all");
    __av_register_all_proc();

    ::AVFormatContext * ctx = NULL;
    int err = __avformat_open_input_proc(&ctx, "g:\\Media\\The Sneezing Baby Panda.flv", NULL, NULL);
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. As of now, I'm getting an `unresolved external symbol` error for `avformat_open_input`. Is your code meant to include the `lib` files too? Because I was trying to get the task accomplished purely with the ffmpeg DLL's of the shared build (wouldn't mind knowing how to do it with the dev builds either. I was running into some errors when I tried with the dev builds)

Comment: Typically use a static library (ffmpeg\lib\libavformat.dll.a) to access the dynamic runtime libraries. If for some reason it's impossible, try to use 'GetProcAddress(hInstLibrary, "avformat_open_input")' function, as shown here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686944(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The unresolved external symbol error I was getting was in the line I had used GetProcAddress. I'm using the inttypes.h file downloaded from http://code.google.com/p/msinttypes/downloads/list because common.h needs it. Even when I include the libs, I get this `Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl av_register_all(void)" (?av_register_all@@YAXXZ) referenced in function _main F:\Projects\VisualStudio\ffmpegTestProgram\ffmpegTestProgram\main.obj`

Comment: Tried your program (after removing `stdafx`, converting `_TCHAR` to `char` and `_tmain` to `main`). It built successfully. Thank you so very much! :) I just hope I'd be able to use the API's to get the rgb values into a char array, as I originally wanted.